# Tracking number of accordion expands/open as a goal

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, goal-tracking

I'm using accordion component to break a large content into logical sections. Each section is triggered by a link click that also changes URL #anchor.

The accordion HTML markup looks like this (http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/accordion.html):

```
<ul class="accordion" data-accordion>
  <li class="accordion-navigation">
    <a href="#panel1a" class="header">Accordion 1</a>
    <div id="panel1a" class="content active">
      Panel 1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="accordion-navigation">
    <a href="#panel2a" class="header">Accordion 2</a>
    <div id="panel2a" class="content">
      Panel 2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Right now I'm tracking every accordion expand/collapse action with link-click to CSS selector (`".accordion .header"`) as an event.

I would like to also track this goals:

- **At least one** accordion content was clicked (expanded/collapsed) during the visit.
- **At least half** of accordion content sections were clicked (expanded/collapsed) during the visit.
- **All** of accordion content sections were clicked (expanded/collapsed) during the visit.

It is not possible to trigger a goal based on multiple events in Google Analytics (https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/28278/analiytics-can-i-set-a-goal-on-multiple-events), so I was thinking I should track a new events based on my needs: **one-clicked**, **half-clicked**, **all-clicked** and then create goals to these events.

To create new events specified above I was thinking about building a JS array that would hold each click. On each new click the array would be checked and if the conditions are met, new event would be recorded.

How can I do this with JavaScript triggers and variables in Google Tag Manager? Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, I would be doing all the necessary logic to work out when these goals have been accomplished in the client side and then send off a unique event to GA via GTM when you know they've been achieved.

Each time your logic calculates that a goal has been acheived you would push an event to the datalayer and you may want to make this event generic across all goals but add a data item to to tell you which goal is achieved (this shows the 'at least one accordian is clicked'):

```
dataLayer.push({
  'event':'goal_complete',
  'goaltype':'single'
});
```

Then in GTM you'd create a trigger of type custom event where the event name is 'goal_complete'.  You also create a variable of type dataLayer which looks for the value of 'goaltype'.

To complete the functionality, create a GA event tag which has the appropriate category/action/label/value as necessary.  You may want to use the goaltype DL item in either action or label depending on your setup.

Finally, fire this tag on the trigger you created.